# Converting to Web Application Project: EntityFramework/DataAnnotations type exists error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, vs-web-site-project, vs-web-application-project

I'm working to convert an old Web Site project to a Web Application Project and I've run into this issue with no help from the compiler as to what I need to look at or possibly change.

Here's the full text of the error:
"The type 'ColumnAttribute' exists in both 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'" error

Here's the lines in a cs file that are getting the error (in an entity class):

```
[Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
[Required]
public string r_roleDescription { get; set; }
```

The line with "Column(TypeName..." is highlighted with the error.

Any ideas?

Comment: That really has nothing to do with switching from Website Project to Web Application Project. That's just a simple case of the same name being used for two different classes in two different assemblies. The solution is to either fully qualify some or all of your class references, or eliminate one of the assemblies if it's not needed, potentially remove any using statements that aren't necessary etc. Do you understand how namespaces work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. It turns out that the problem was the compiler getting lost because of too many errors. I copied over the files from the website project to the web application project one at a time, fixing errors as they appeared, and this error went away.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use the full namespace path to specify which you actually want to use:

```cs
// If you want the DataAnnotation:
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
[Required]
public string r_roleDescription { get; set; }
```

The compiler just needs you to tell it how to resolve it since there are two possibilities (Entity and ComponentModel).